# I have a custom cell in a ListView. How can do I make it highlighted on touch?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I want my cells in my ListView to highlight on touch (just like they do normally with an unmodified ListView). How do I do that with a cell that I've modified?

Here is what my cell looks like:

[image]

And here is the XML of my cell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="34dip"
        android:stretchColumns="0"
        android:divider="@null"       
         >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/plaincell"
            android:divider="@null"  >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtKey"
                android:text="Some text"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
            />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtValue"
                android:text="Some text"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
            />

        </TableRow>

  </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your background drawable should be a [state list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) that has different graphics for different states (for example, pressed, focused, neither).

Edit: To use solid colors, you can do this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@color/pressedcolor" android:state_pressed="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@color/unpressedcolor" />
</selector>
```

You can then define your own colors in a resource file:

```
<resources>
    <color name="pressedcolor">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="unpressedcolor">#0000ff</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Is there no way to just do it with a simple solid color?

Comment: From elsewhere on the same page that I linked to: "Note: A color resource can also be used as a drawable in XML. For example, when creating a state list drawable, you can reference a color resource for the android:drawable attribute (android:drawable="@color/green")." So you can just use a solid color as each of the item's drawables.

Answer (score 2):

make the background of your LinearLayout a selector drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/myClickedStateDrawable" android:state_pressed="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/myNonClickedStateDrawable" />
</selector>
```

where myClickedStateDrawable, myNonClickedStateDrawable are drawables that define the background of your Layout

hope this helps

Comment: Is there no way to just do it with a simple solid color?

Comment: Sure. Use the selector with the non-focused color and another color for all the rest. You don't have to use shapes.

Comment: Actually, the format should be '<item android:drawable="@color/green"/>'. You can define your color resources separately.

Answer (score 1):

I see what is happening, **but first**:

- most layouts that only have one child can be removed,
- also a TableLayout and TableRow are both based off of the LinearLayout class.

So really you have *three* LinearLayouts where you only need *one*.

**The problem:**
I assume that this line sets a new background color that covers the entire layout:

```
android:background="@drawable/plaincell"
```

This also covers or overrides the default ListView color selector.
You might want to look into [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) if you are changing the backgrounds and text color attributes of every UI element on the screen. If you set these attributes in a Theme then you shouldn't need to create a new color selector to do what the old color selector did already.